# l'Hôpital and substitution give different limits

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Find $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x-x+\frac{x^3}6}{x^3}$$

L'Hospital 3 times:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x-x+\frac{x^3}6}{x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{\cos x - 1 + \frac{x^2}2}{3x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-\sin x+x}{6x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-\cos x +1}{6}=0$$

L'Hospital once and Substitution:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x-x+\frac{x^3}6}{x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{\cos x - 1 + \frac{x^2}2}{3x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^2}{6x^2}=\frac16$$

Comment: $\cos x-1+\frac{x^2}2=1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\cdots-1+\frac{x^2}2\ne\frac{x^2}2$. But what do you call *substitution* here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one is wrong. How did you drop $\frac {\cos x-1} {3x^{2}}$? The limit of this part is $-\frac  16$ which cancels with the limit of the other term.

It is also not clear as to what you mean by 'substitution'.

Comment: Ahh I have incorrectly applied the rule $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x \to a}f(x)}{\lim_{x \to a}g(x)}$